# JavaScript focusout and specific key

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
$(selectorClass).focusout(function (e) {
```

which is triggering if the focus is changed, but how can I modify this so that it also triggers if the enter key is pressed?

Anyone have any examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can factorise your code calling the same function in both events :

```js
function MyCallBack(e)
{
    // Your event code goes there
    console.log("called");
}

$("#test").focusout(MyCallBack);
$("#test").on('keypress', function(e)
{
    if(e.which == 13) // check enter/return key
        MyCallBack(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already **written code for focusout event**, all you need to just **trigger the event** when enter key is pressed.

jQuery [trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) can be used.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
   if (e.key === "13") { // check enter/return key
      $(selectorClass).trigger("focusout");
    }
});
```